# R: Extract unique values in columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a dataframe in R and I wonder if it is possible to retrieve values of a column that are not present in the others columns and this for each column.

```
My dataframe looks like :

sample_1 sample_2 sample_3
   a        a        a       
   c        e        c
   d        f        e
   g        m        j
   m        n        n
   x        u        w
   t        z        z
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
sample_1 sample_2 sample_3
   d        f        j
   g        u        w
   x
   t
```

Thank you in advance for your answers,

Comment: Note that data.frames in R also have the same number of rows across all columns, which is why akrun filled the second and third column with empty strings (""). Since you want to capture three vectors of different length, I'd suggest sticking with a `list` structure (the output of lapply) which is more flexible, i.e. its elements can have different types and dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(df1), function(i) df1[,i][!df1[,i] %in%
                      unique(unlist(df1[-i]))])
 library(stringi)
 as.data.frame(stri_list2matrix(lst, fill=''))
```

Comment: Or similarly: `lapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) setdiff(df[,i], unlist(df[-i])))`